# How to dismiss a view in code after two seconds

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have a UICOllectionView that contains several UIIMages (No use of storyboards). When the user taps an Image a view is placed inside of the specific UIImage which contains an information for the user. I want that this view deletes it self automatically after 2 seconds. Can someone please give me an example how to achieve that. I didn't find any solution. I know that I can dismiss a view very easy by saying View.removeFromSuperView(). Can someone please make a short example PLEASE

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can execute a block of code after 2 seconds using Grand Central Dispatch

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    // code to remove your view
}
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks Bro

Comment: I wanted to do it bro but got this problem : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: FYI, It's a bad idea to access a view after a delay. Say the view is not accessible after one second, it will result in a crash. But since I do not have a better answer, I am not voting :P

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
let viewss = UIView()
```

**In ViewDidLoad**

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { (timer) in
            self.viewss.isHidden = true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a performAfter function which uses `Swift 3` GCD asyncAfter function internally like

```
func performAfter(delay: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

and use

```
performAfter(delay: 2) {
   print("task to be done")
}
```